# Memory management in iphone cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an ebook app for the iPhone using cocos2d. I use over 150 images(I guess). The problem is, while turning from one page to another, images get hanged randomly......

I tried this also `[[TextureMgr sharedTextureMgr] removeAllTextures];` but in vain. I guess the the problem is with the memory. Below is my code for all pages:

```
-(id)init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        [SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine];
        NSLog(@"b4 cover");
        Sprite *bg1 = [Sprite spriteWithFile:@"a.jpg"];
        bg1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        [self addChild:bg1 z:-1];
        once = TRUE;
        soundId = [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@".mp3"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) transitionfront:(id) sender
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopEffect:soundId];
    soundId1 = [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"page_turn.mp3"];
    flip = [[Sprite spriteWithFile:@"a.jpg"] retain];
    [self addChild: flip z:1];
    [flip setPosition:ccp(160,240)];
    Animation* animation1 = [Animation animationWithName:@"Page1" delay:0.09];
    for( int i=1;i<4;i++)
        [animation1 addFrameWithFilename: [NSString stringWithFormat:@".jpg", i]];

    id action = [Animate actionWithAnimation: animation1];
    //id action = [RepeatForever actionWithAction:[Animate actionWithAnimation: animation1]]; 
    [flip runAction:action];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(moveforward) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void) moveforward
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopEffect:soundId1];
    [[Director sharedDirector] replaceScene: [ [Scene node] addChild: [nextpage node] z:0] ];
}

-(void) transitionback:(id) sender
{
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopEffect:soundId];
    soundId1 = [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@".mp3"];

    flip = [[Sprite spriteWithFile:@".jpg"] retain];
    [self addChild: flip z:1];
    [flip setPosition:ccp(160,240)];
    Animation* animation1 = [Animation animationWithName:@"Page1" delay:0.09];
    for( int i=3;i>0;i--)
        [animation1 addFrameWithFilename: [NSString stringWithFormat:@".jpg", i]];

    id action = [Animate actionWithAnimation: animation1];
    //id action = [RepeatForever actionWithAction:[Animate actionWithAnimation: animation1]]; 
    [flip runAction:action];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(movebackward) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void) movebackward{
    //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]stopEffect:@".mp3"];
    [[Director sharedDirector]replaceScene:[[Scene node]addChild:[b4page node] z:0]];
}

-(void) glossary :(id) sender {
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]stopEffect:soundId];
    [[Director sharedDirector]replaceScene:[[Scene node]addChild:[ node] z:0]];
}

-(BOOL)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint cocosTouchPoint = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint point = [[Director sharedDirector] convertToGL:cocosTouchPoint];

    NSLog(@"pointx: %f pointy:%f", point.x, point.y);

    // Was a tab touched, if so, which one...
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(220, 0, 100, 70), point))
    {
        if(once)
        {
            NSLog(@"enterred page1");

            [self transitionfront:nil];
            once = FALSE;
        }
    }
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(0,0,60,60), point))
    {
        if(once)
        {
            NSLog(@"enterred cover");

            [self transitionback:nil];
            once = FALSE;
        }
    }

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(100, 15, 30, 30), point))
    {
        if(once){
            [self glossary :nil];
            once = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return kEventHandled;
}

-(void)playEffect:(NSString*)sound{
    if(effectPlayer!=nil){
        [effectPlayer release];
    }
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound ofType:@"mp3"]];
    effectPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [effectPlayer setDelegate:self];

    [effectPlayer play];
}

-(void)stopEffect
{
    [effectPlayer stop];
}

-(void) dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

do pls help me........ do give me a exact coding

this is the err.....

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: aesop.mp3)'
2010-05-27 10:43:09.834 abc[276:20b] Stack: (
    11674715,
    2476006971,
    11758651,
    11758490,
    5126917,
    660698,
    660881,
    661061,
    131577,
    448857,
    120432,
    153433,
    630890,
    23694899,
    23603228,
    23630005,
    47120081,
    11459456,
    11455560,
    47114125,
    47114322,
    23633923,
    9928,
    9814
)
```

Comment: Could you format your code into something readable? There's a little button on the editor to help you with that.

Comment: Definitely reformat your code!  Based on the error your inserting a nil value for your key into a dictionary.  Probably best to start and see why that value is coming out nil.  I'd be happy to look through your code but please reformat first.

Comment: I've never used cocos2d, but your calls to [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@".mp3"] don't seem to specify an actual mp3 to play. Is that right?

Comment: First of all why are you using empty files like .mp3 and .jpg.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean for "went vain"?

I had a similar issue and when you choose to removeAllTextures you loose all the images that you have in memory and then your App won't find anymore the file related to the CCSprites.

This is because CCSprite initWithFile method adds the texture to the sharedTextureCache:

```
-(id) initWithFile:(NSString*)filename
{
    NSAssert(filename!=nil, @"Invalid filename for sprite");
    CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: filename];
    if( texture ) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
        rect.size = texture.contentSize;
        return [self initWithTexture:texture rect:rect];
    }

    [self release];
    return nil;
}
```

Also in this line you are missing "%i" to refer to the int when craeting the String with format:

```
[animation1 addFrameWithFilename: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.jpg", i]];
```

Also you are using Animation but you should use CCAnimation, e.g.:

```
CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:0.1f];
```

Does this help?